# why JWT token is still avaliable after removing from local storage

Tags: jwt

After removing the JWT from local storage, why token is sent in the HTTP header for a node API call? When I go to the previous page using the browser's back button and perform any action( in angular 6).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the browser is caching the JWT for some reason.  But, this should not really be a security issue for you, because typically your Node application would always have to verify that an incoming JWT is valid and can be trusted.  The usual workflow for a request coming to your Node application would look something like this:

- The browser sends a request to some endpoint in your Node application, including the JWT
- The Node application receives the JWT
- It might check the claims, but also
- It would check for things such as the user's status, perhaps by hitting a database table

A JWT is not, and should not be treated as, a license to unconditionally access your Node application.  Things like claims are independent of the browser state, so this caching issue should not be a real problem.  And, most of the time, your Node app would want to run additional checks on the server side.